# Fortune algorithm for voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-geometry, fortran, software-recommendation, voronoi-diagrams

Although there are many algorithms to construct Voronoi diagram, some of them are faster than others. Based on my knowledge Fortune algorithm is fastest for construct Voronoi diagram either in two dimensional or three dimensional. I search many forums but can't find any Fortune algorithm([Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm)) code or a hint for Fortran.

So my question is: Is there any free Fortran code for Fortune algorithm in two dimensions or three dimensions?

Also, any kind of hint that makes the code writing easy for me is acceptable, for example flowchart. I don't know really it right to ask free source code here, so if I do wrong forgive me.

Comment: I found this one in GitHub: https://github.com/lanl/voronoi

Comment: @hardmath I added a wiki link for Fortune's algorithm.

Comment: The [netlib repository](http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/search.pl) has several Voronoi related packages, including Steve Fortune's 2D [sweepline implementation in C](http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/sweep2).  These are free for anyone to use, but come without support and may require [licensing for commercial use](http://www.netlib.org/srwn/srwn21.html) with some packages.  Perhaps you can search for "sweepline Fortran" to find additional resources?

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks so much. I read that code I found that it is based on output of another prog.